# How to rename "I'm not a robot" in reCaptcha

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I want to change name of "I'm not a robot" in reCaptcha in its file, but I didn't find where to edit. Can anybody help me to rename it?
So Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is not possible to change that.

but i found this on internet ... check whether it works:

> This is not possible because the Same Origin Policy prohibits any
>   script (that's on your site) trying to access an iframe (the captcha)
>   that has another origin (Google server).
>
> We should be no problem running the code below if we own both servers
>   :)

```
$( ".g-recaptcha > div > div > iframe" ).contents().find( "#recaptcha-anchor-label" ).text('Custom Text');
```